# How to use Like query in objectify

Tags: objectify, datastore

I want to search a sub string in url text in db.
Like `%substring%`.
How to solve this using `objectify`?

```java
if(url != null) {
    xoloWebHistoryQ=xoloWebHistoryQ.filter("url >=", url);
    xoloWebHistoryQ=xoloWebHistoryQ.filter("url <", url+"\ufffd");
}
```

I tried it with above code, but it didn't return *urls*, that *substrings* are in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for fulltext search. This is not something the datastore is good at - actually, most databases are pretty poor at it which is why we have specialized databases like Elasticsearch.

If you want to fake it with the datastore, you can. Create a synthetic, indexed List property that you populate in an @OnSave method. Fill it with all the things you want to match: 'substring', 'ubstring', 'bstring', 'ubs', etc. Then do equality matches against this field. Be careful, you can end up with huge indexes this way, but if your data is compact enough it will work.

If you want "real" full text search, replicate data out of the datastore to something else that is better at this kind of indexing. There are hosted Elasticsearch services. GAE/Standard has an old FTS service that works quite well (although it might not be a good long-term solution). You could even use Postgres if your needs are simple.